# absolute height generate unrollable ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a situation about in using ListView and found that if I set up a absolute height let say 100dp, then the ListView become unrollable even though items do out of bound. However, this won't happen when I set the height as wrap_content, but this must be fill in the whole screen if the item list is longer than the screen size. I do need a ListView that stay above a control bar that is in the bottom of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout >
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/eventitems"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget53"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <Button />
        <EditText />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

now, if the Item list is longer enough, the bottom item won't show and the ListView can't be rolled. if wrap_content, the latest item will show under the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout >
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/eventitems"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="warp_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/widget53"/>
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/widget53"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         >
        <Button />
        <EditText />
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this.. Note that I have added a layout_above attribute to the listview and removed the parenttop from your LinearLayout and added a parentbottom attribute.